# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNSound.IsAndroid')

Tags: react-native, react-native-sound

I am trying to get react-native-sound to work on my react-native app but I keep getting this error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNSound.IsAndroid').

I have noticed that any people have received this error and I found a relevant question already on here, but I am super noobie and don't understand most of the solutions people have suggested.

I have tried react-native link react-native-sound, but it did not change anything. From reading people's comments I must now manually Install, but I don't really understand what I am doing. Even step one... go to android/app/src/main/java/.../MainApplication.java. I don't understand this as I can't see an android file anywhere. I am using Visual Studio (windows 10) and expo cli with my own Pixel 2 plugged in (hence I am not using Android Studio).

Any help would be fantastic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't use native modules with projects which is created by expo cli. 
So, either you can use alternative package for expo which is https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/audio/

or if you are familiar with native development, you can eject your project from expo to use native android/ios project with react-native cli.

Comment: Thanks for this - the alternate package works fine. I would prefer to eject and use android Studio, but my computer can't hack it!